# java conditional statement checking

Tags: java, swing

I'm in a beginning java course and I have a conditional statement that I'm trying to check without using if/if else statements. I have written it to check for a blank textfield but... it's not working correctly. Here is a copy of the code that I wrote, can anyone please tell me what's wrong?

```
String nameCheck = (nameField.getText() == "")? "Please enter a name" : "Hello, " + nameField.getText();
```

Comment: Alternatively, consider `String#isEmpty`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to replace

```
nameField.getText() == ""
```

with

```
nameField.getText().equals("");
```

The double equals operator checks if the two strings are the exact same object, whereas the "equals()" method will check if the strings have the same value.

Comment: While I agree that this will work and indeed it does, we(the class) haven't covered this yet, and the teacher frowns a little on using code/statements/syntax that we haven't covered.

Comment: @user2067237 I'm "fairly certain" the teacher covered `equals`. But if not, you should learn about it and use it anyway. `==` is always *incorrect* for equality of non-primitive values. (And it's a darn shame this isn't flagged as a huge warning ..)

Comment: LOL, I'm sure she did cover it, it's entirely possible that I zoned a little on that part of the lecture

Comment: If it's necessary, kufudo's solution works just as well (if not better, since it treats an input with all whitespace as blank) but without using `equals`.

Comment: Just went back through the lecture slides from when we covered the conditional string checking, she did indeed cover .equals, thank you very much for refocusing my attention on the solution

Answer (score 1):

A better approach may be:

```
String nameCheck = (nameField.getText().trim().length() == 0)? "Please enter a name" : "Hello, " + nameField.getText();
```

This checks to see if the string is empty or full of white-spaces.

Answer (score 0):

```
String nameCheck = (nameField.getText().equals(""))? "Please enter a name" : "Hello, " + nameField.getText();
```